# How to add to the list HEX values while preserving their original form

Tags: python, hex

This is my code:

```
First_xor_list=[0xaa,0x89,0xc4,0xfe,0x46]
Secpnd_xor_list=[0x78,0xf0,0xd0,0x03,0xe7]
after_xor=[]
xor_helper=[]
name = "UserNa"

after_xor.append(hex(ord(name[0])))#first stage - xor from second char to    end and add the second char to the end of  the list
for i in range(len(name)):
    if i < len(name)-1:
        after_xor.append(hex((First_xor_list[i])^ (ord(name[i+1]))))
    elif i < len(name):
        after_xor.append(hex(ord(name[1])))
```

The problem is that the values go into the list as a String,This is the output:

```
['0x55', '0xd9', '0xec', '0xb6', '0xb0', '0x27', '0x73']
```

And because I have to do XOR with the values in the list I need them like this:

```
[0x55, 0xd9, 0xec, 0xb6, 0xb0, 0x27, 0x73]
```

How can I add them to the list in this way?

Comment: You can't have them in a list *"as hex"*; they will appear as integers with the same value (`[85, 217, 236, 182, 176, 39, 115]`), as that's the default representation. Get rid of the `hex` call.

Comment: Exactly the way you did it in the first 2 lines.

Comment: I cant store them as an HEX values at all? only as an int ? are you shure ?

Comment: hex is a string that represents a number .... binary is a string that represents a number .... octal is a string that represents a number ... ints and floats are those numbers that the other strings represent (gross oversimplification but meh)

Comment: *"store them as an HEX values"* doesn't make sense conceptually. Hex, decimal, binary, octal are all just **representations** of a number; by default, Python *shows it* in decimal, but underneath it's all binary. Try it in the interpreter - if you type `0x55` (hex representation), you will see `85` (decimal representation).

Answer (score 1):

Delete hex, hex only converts the int to a string containing his hexadecimal form.

```
First_xor_list=[0xaa,0x89,0xc4,0xfe,0x46]
Secpnd_xor_list=[0x78,0xf0,0xd0,0x03,0xe7]
after_xor=[]
xor_helper=[]
name = "UserNa"

after_xor.append(ord(name[0]))#first stage - xor from second char to    end and add the second char to the end of  the list
for i in range(len(name)):
    if i < len(name)-1:
        after_xor.append((First_xor_list[i])^ (ord(name[i+1])))
    elif i < len(name):
        after_xor.append(ord(name[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you ,but i try to do the transfar as an HEX value not an int value,this is why i used th hex() in thr first place . are thare is a way to add this to a list as an "int" of HAX ?

Answer (score 0):

The function `hex` convert a number into a string in the hexadecimal basis. 
To do calculations, just leave the `hex` out and keep the elements as numbers:

```
after_xor.append(ord(name[0])) # first stage - xor from second char to    end and add the second char to the end of  the list
for x, ch in zip(First_xor_list, name[1:]):
    after_xor.append(x^ord(ch))
after_xor.append(ord(name[1]))
```